# Using INDEX & MATCH or VLOOKUP twice and returning a third column

Tags: excel, match, vlookup, assign

I have tried all day long but unfortunately I am unable to come up with the correct formula.

My columns have the respective information.

COLUMN A - season_id

COLUMN B - team_id

COLUMN C - (**this is where I intend to write up the formula**)

I have a separate table that contains 'games played' details. In this table, the columns contain the respective.

COLUMN E - match_id

COLUMN F - season_id

COLUMN J - team_id

Please note, the 'games played' table has many repeating instances, like a team playing 10 times or more, but for the first table there are no repeating instances. I want to insert my formula in the first table (COLUMN C) such that, if value of cell A1 matches COLUMN F **AND** value of cell B1 matches COLUMN J, then return the first occurrence from COLUMN E.

I have tried using the below formula but with no luck. It displays results but they are not accurate and some display errors. My list is quite large.

```
=INDEX(E:E,IFERROR(MATCH(A1,F:F,0),MATCH(B1,J:J,0)))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one:

```
=INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A1 & "|" & B2,F:F & "|" & J:J,0))
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it